# How do I add upper error bars to bar charts in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm comparing the sum of monthly values of 5 years from two datasets by creating bar plots. I want to add upper error bars.
Here are my codes for bar plots:

```
library(tibble)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

tb = tibble(Date = seq(mdy('1/1/1997'), mdy('12/31/1999'), by = '1 week')) %>% 
  mutate(sum_sed= sample(0:10, n(), replace=TRUE)) %>% 
  group_by(Month = month(Date, label = TRUE), 
           year = as.integer(year(Date)))

tb2 = tibble(Date = seq(mdy('1/1/1997'), mdy('12/31/1999'), by = '1 week')) %>% 
  mutate(sum_sed= sample(11:20, n(), replace=TRUE)) %>%
  group_by(Month = month(Date, label = TRUE), 
           year = as.integer(year(Date)))

tb_all <- bind_rows(tb %>% 
                      mutate(Month = month(Date, label = TRUE), 
                             Year = as.integer(year(Date))),
                    tb2 %>% 
                      mutate(Month = month(Date, label = TRUE), 
                             Year = as.integer(year(Date)))) %>% 
  group_by(Model, Year, Month) %>% 
  summarize(Sum_Sed_yield = sum(Sed_yield))

## plotting bar chart

tb_all %>% 
  ggplot(aes(factor(Month), Sum_Sed_yield, fill = Model))+ 
  geom_bar(stat ="identity", position = "dodge")+
  facet_wrap(vars(Year), nrow = 1)+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, size = 9))
```

How can I add upper error bars to each bar?

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example.](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/reprex-dos-and-donts.html)

Comment: `tb = tibble(Date = seq(mdy('1/1/1997'), mdy('12/31/1999'), by = '1 week')) %>%
  mutate(sum_sed= sample(0:10, n(), replace=TRUE)) %>%
  group_by(Month = month(Date, label = TRUE), year = as.integer(year(Date)))
tb `
for tb2
`tb2 = tibble(Date = seq(mdy('1/1/1997'), mdy('12/31/1999'), by = '1 week')) %>%
  mutate(sum_sed= sample(11:20, n(), replace=TRUE)) %>%
  group_by(Month = month(Date, label = TRUE), year = as.integer(year(Date)))
tb2`